# Why is my HtmlElement's FirstChild property null when there are valid child elements present?

Tags: c#, .net, null, webbrowser-control

I'm writing a program that scrapes data from a website using the Windows Forms WebBrowser control.

I have stored an HtmlElement representing a table row (`<tr>` tag) in a variable named `row`. Subsequent code using `row.FirstChild` returns null.

When I run `? row` in the Visual Studio Immediate Window, the output includes the following seemingly contradictory lines. (Data has been sanitized by replacing letters with 'Z' and numbers with 0; spaces remain intact; line breaks have been added for readability).

```
Children: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection}
FirstChild: null
InnerHtml: "\n\t\t<td class=\"rgGroupCol\">&nbsp;</td><td>00000000</td>
           <td>ZZZ 000</td><td>Text Remvd I: Zzzzzzzz Zzzzzzzzz</td><td>0</td>
           <td>Zzzzzzzzz</td><td>Zz</td>
           <td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t00:00 Z 00:00 Z\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>
           <td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t0/00/0000 to 00/00/0000\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>
           <td>Zzzzz Zzzzzzzz 000</td><td>Zzzzz Z Zzzzzzz</td>\n\t"
```

It seems to me that since the `InnerHtml` string has several tags clearly present, `FirstChild` should not be null. Indeed, when I expand the `Children` property in the Locals window, its `Count` is 11, and I can expand the Results View to see the individual tags that I expect.

The owners of the website recently updated it and introduced numerous HTML and script errors; however, the W3C Validator does not report any errors in this portion of the page, and I don't see any problems with these tags either. I do have `ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true` set on my `WebBrowser` object, and I have set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\MyProg.vshost.exe` to 10001.

Environment details:

- Windows 8 Pro 64-bit with Windows Media Center
- Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16635
- Using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control in C# 5.0 in .NET 4.5 compiled to 64-bit executable

What am I missing here? How can `FirstChild` be null when there are clearly children present? If there is some problem with the HTML that I am not seeing, how can I work around it without changing the page (which belongs to someone else)?

**WORKAROUND**
Faced with code that was working and then suddenly quit working, I was so fixated on finding the cause that I completely missed the obvious workaround. It jumped out at me the next night, and here it is. I simply replaced `row.FirstChild` with `row.Children[0]`, and the rest of my code ran unchanged and successfully. Of course, this does not explain the behavior I was seeing, but it does get me past it.

Comment: As you describe it (`element.Children.Count == 11 && element.FirstChild  == null`) , it looks to me like a bug in WebBrowser interop code.